# Merging writable node streams into one stream

Tags: node.js, gulp, node.js-stream

I have an array of writable streams in a gulp task. I would like to merge them and return one stream. I am using the merge-stream node module to do this. I get the following error though.

```
[14:22:56] Error: Cannot pipe, not readable
    at WriteStream.Writable.pipe (_stream_writable.js:161:22)
    at add (C:\workspace\mediafly-viewer\desktop\node_modules\merge-stream\index.js:28:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Is merging writable streams supported? If so, how do I go about doing this?

Here is what I tried with promises.

```
const promises = streams.map(s => new Promise((resolve, reject) => s.on('finish', resolve).on('error', reject)));

return Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: You can't pipe an unreadable (e.g. write-only) stream into  a writeable stream. Would you consider turning one writeable stream into a `transform` (duplex) stream or is this not possible?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure. The goal was to get notified when all streams have finished writing. I was able to get this done with promises, but it is not very clean. Posting it as a possible solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `merge-stream` treats each stream as a [Transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams), i.e. it tries to [call](https://github.com/grncdr/merge-stream/blob/1b33da64b219dcc8bf33645953c32a6fd9e3b36d/index.js#L29) `pipe` on the writable stream, but writable streams do not have `pipe` method, only `write`. What you can do to fix this is to either use [Transform streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform) for your writes, or do as you've done by using Promise to wait for the [`finish`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event.

Comment: Could you give an example of how to turn a write stream (like fs.createWriteStream) into a readable one?